# How do I use a policy on an index that doesn't use the model the policy belongs to?

Tags: laravel, authorization

What I am trying to do is apply a policy on a control method that lists a bunch of records instead of just one record like most of the examples I have seen.

Instead of checking against the `ThoughtRecords` I want to check the signed in user hashedId to the user that's being queried hashedId in the controller `index()` method.

Apparently [in the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#via-middleware) the model class needs to be passed on actions that don't require a model. So I'm confused how to make this work.

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\ThoughtRecord' => 'App\Policies\ThoughtRecordPolicy',
];

public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
}
```

**ThoughtRecordPolicy.php**

```
public function view(User $signedInUser, User $client)
{
    //return true;
    dd('Policy working');
    //return $signedInUser->id === $client->id;
}
```

**ThoughtRecordController.php**

```
public function index($userHashedId)
{
    $client = User::where('hashed_id', $userHashedId)->first();

    $this->authorize('view', ThoughtRecord::class, $client);

    $records = ThoughtRecord::where('user_id', $client->id)->latest()->paginate(1);

    return ThoughtRecordResource::collection($records);
}
```

**Error**

> Too few arguments to function App\Policies\ThoughtRecordPolicy::view()

I have also tried:

`$this->authorize('view', $client);`

> This action is unauthorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said:

> Apparently in the Laravel docs the model class needs to be passed on actions that don't require a model. So I'm confused how to make this work.

You need pass both the `ThoughtRecord::class` and the `$client` into an array:

`$this->authorize('view', [ThoughtRecord::class, $client]);`